# listbox selectionmode = multiextended how to get rid of selecting items with mousekey down

Tags: c#, .net, listbox

When Setting the listbox selectionmode to multiextended I observed three ways to select items:

1. pressing mouse key while holding shift key
2. pressing mouse key while holding ctrl key
3. pressing mouse key while moving mouse over unselected item

1 and 2. is exactly the behaviour I want but I dont' want 3.
because later I want to rearrange items by moving all selected items up and down with the mouse.

How to get rid of 3. ?

I need a behaviour just like the playlist in Winamp. Rearrange items by dragging and copy paste items

Answer (score 9):

The ListBox class has two SelectionMode. Multiple or Extended.

> In Multiple mode, you can select or deselect any item by clicking it. In Extended mode, you need to hold 
>   down the Ctrl key to select additional items or the Shift key to select a range of items.

Just proper property need to be set.

Comment: There is multisimple and multiexteded mode.

In multisimple mode I cannot use crtl and shift key

Comment: ur talking about Win Forms? my post is about WPF

Comment: @tomfox66 you should have tagged you question appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You want the "Extended" mode but do not want mouse drag selections unless a shift or control key is pressed.  Rather that trying to back out features, you should add features.  Try this.

- Set "KeyPreview" on your form to
  "True".
- Set SelectionMode for your
  ListBox back to "MultiSimple".

Use this code to add the ability to select items when Control or Shift is pressed.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private bSelectMode As Boolean = False

    Private Sub Form1_KeyUpOrDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown, Me.KeyUp
        bSelectMode = e.Control OrElse e.Shift
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListBox1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.MouseMove
        If bSelectMode AndAlso e.Button <> Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.None Then
            Dim selectedindex = ListBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.Location)

            If selectedindex <> -1 Then
                ListBox1.SelectedItems.Add(ListBox1.Items(selectedindex))
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```